# How do I create nav menu for a cms?

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system

I'm creating a cms, I want to produce a set of unordered lists for a nav drop down menu. First, I select all of the menus and links from the database, then I want them to be outputed as unordered lists using php (including the 'main' list's 'child' list if there is one)
How do I do it?

```
Main list->         <li><a href="#">Products</a>
                    <ul>
       Child list-> <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried anything yet.... I'm also confused about how I'm gonna create the nav menu database....

Comment: In this case I recommend you start at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, can you give me any tips on how to create it? Just to be sure that I'm on the right track..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you get from database is stored as an array, you can do a foreach loop and iterate over the database result and do like this:

```
  <li><a href="#">Products</a>
  <?php 
  foreach($rows as $value)
  {
  //these are the child list items you got from database
  echo "<ul><li><a href="#">".$value."</a></li></ul>";
  } 
  ?>
  </li>
```