# Designing nav menu database for a cms

Tags: sql

This relates to my previous question -> [How do I create nav menu for a cms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410990/how-do-i-create-nav-menu-for-a-cms)

How do I design the database for it?

Answer (score 0):

depend what do you want to appear in that navigation menu, for example if you follow wordpress logic you can have categories or pages in the navigation menu.
if you decide to have pages there, ten you simply create a tblPages database table and in it you create the following basic columns: id, title, description, date, order.
the title will be shown in navmenu, description will be shown on click as well as the date, the order will be used to specify the order in the navmenu.

If you decide to have categories in the navigation menu, then you will need categories table with those columns id, title, order, and another table posts with the following fields: id, titile, shorttext, fulltext, views, categoryid (this is foreign key of id in categories table), publicationdate, author ...

Comment: How do I create the childlist menus?

Comment: tell me which approach you will use, categories or pages?

Comment: the best way to do is by creating a new table with two fields: categoryid and parentid. And you can decide that if parentid is equal to 0 then it is the main menu, and if it is 1 or more it is child of category with that id.
Or if you dont want to create another table you can add a field in te current table parentid and follow te same logic as i told.

PS. if you set categoryid = 0 to be the main category field, then you have to start the category or page id from 1 not from 0.